# Show that any compact set in $\mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum of an operator on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to find an example of a bounded linear operator, who's spectrum is any compact set $K\subset\mathbb{C}$.
Now I know this question has been asked before and many answers gives examples of Hilbert Space. Specifically the sequence space $l^2$ (the set of square summable sequences) and the operator that takes $\{e_n\}$ to $\{a_ne_n\}$ where ${a_n}$ is a dense sequence in $K$. Again, assume we don't know anything about Hilbert spaces so we can't bring up inner products. Does this mapping still work and does it work for any $l^p$ for $p \neq 2$

Comment: What is the question, exactly? It looks that you already have an answer...

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try to prove it?  If $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb C$, then the map $(x_1,x_2,\dots) \mapsto (a_1x_1,a_2x_2,\dots)$ is a well defined bounded linear operator on $l^p$ and has spectrum the closure of the set $\{a_n : n=1,2,\dots\}$.